# help with sin and cos

Tags: trigonometry

can someone tell me how this equality arises? I'm stuck :/

$$ 2\cos(2\pi \frac {\omega_1-\omega_2} 2 t  )\sin(2\pi \frac {\omega_1+\omega_2} 2 t  ) = 2\cos(-\frac {2\pi}{10}t )\sin(4\pi t) $$

much appreciated :)

Comment: Are $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ arbitary real numbers ?

Comment: yes. That's all I got

Comment: Seems wrong... if $\omega_1=-\omega_2$ then LHS is always $0$ (for any $t$), while RHS is not.

Comment: Do you have to determine $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ ?

Comment: ...is $t \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I think the RHS needs some $ \omega_1 $ and $ \omega_2 $ factors

Comment: Perhaps try solving $2\pi\frac{\omega_1-\omega_2}{2}t = -\frac{2\pi}{10}t$ and $2\pi\frac{\omega_1+\omega_2}{2}t = 4\pi t$ would be of help

Comment: Well I got it from a exercise book and I checked it again, that's how they wrote it there [to be correct there is an equality before the LHS: the sum of two sin -> sin(2Pi*omega1*t)+sin(2Pi*omega2*t) = LHS above]. Could it by a typo? Because I had similar problems and then it was a typo :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}(1)\enspace2\pi\frac{\omega_1-\omega_2}{2}t &= -\frac{2\pi}{10}t\\
(2)\enspace2\pi\frac{\omega_1+\omega_2}{2}t &= 4\pi t\\[0.5em]
(1) \text{ gives }\omega_1-\omega_2 &= -\frac{1}{5}\\
(2) \text{ gives }\omega_1+\omega_2 &= 8
\end{align}$$

You should be able to determine $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ from here.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is I don't understand how to get the RHS from (1) and (2).

Comment: I can't really say if there's another way, but you have two expression $2\sin(X_1)\cos(Y_1) = 2\sin(X_2)\cos(Y_2)$, thus solving for $X_1 = X_2$ and $Y_1 = Y_2$ is a solution.

Comment: Thank you. I fear this might be a printing error of some sort..something is wrong. Is it possible to "reconstruct" the right equation/simplification then? In other words..where do the omegas go :/

Comment: @holistic as far as I understood the question, the answer would simply be to solve for which $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ this would be true, for which $\omega_1 = \frac{39}{10}$ and $\omega_2 = \frac{1}{10}$ would be true. This means putting these values for the $\omega$'s on the left side would yield the right side.

Comment: ok, I understand! Thank you very much.